# Код на php выполняется неверно

Tags: php

Задача:
Нужно в строке создать ячейки с повторяющимися именами через определенный шаг.

Код:

```
echo "<tr>";
        for ($x=1; $x<39; $x++) {
                $math=($x/5-intval($x/5))*5;
                if ($math == 1) {
                        echo "<td>1</td>";
                } elseif ($math  == 2) {
                        echo "<td>2</td>";
                } elseif ($math  == 3) { 
                        echo "<td>3</td>";   
                } elseif ($math  == 4) { 
                        echo "<td>4</td>";   
                } else { 
                        echo "<td>5</td>";   
                }
        }
echo "</tr>";
```

Должно быть так:
1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 1 | 2 | и так далее.
На деле получается так: 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 5 | 5 | 5 | 4 | 5 | и так далее.

Comment: смотри ответ ОТЛАДКА

Comment: Тут проблема в арифметике с плавающей точкой)

Comment: Спасибо. Возьму отладку на вооружение.

Answer (score 0):

По всей видимости вам нужно воспользоваться операцией деления по модулю:

```php
$math = $x % 5
```

Comment: Спасибо Вам за помощь. Еще не знаю всех возможностей php.